# Как выводить результаты поиска в алфавитном порядке? Bootstrap

Tags: html, django, bootstrap

Не получается выводить результаты поиска на сайте в таблицу в алфавитном поиске. Дело в том, что запрос по внешним ключам. Как это сделать, не понимаю.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type of research</th>
            <th>Drug</th>
            <th>Dosage</th>
            <th>Journal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for post in posts%}
        <tr>
            {% for art in post.fk_article_research.all%}
            <td>{{art.fk_type_of_research}}</td>
            <td>{{art.fk_drug}}</td>
            <td>{{art.dosage}}</td>
            <td>{{art.fk_journal}}</td>
            <td>{% for author in post.fk_author.all %}{{author.name}} 
{%endfor%}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'post_single' pk=post.id %}">{{post.name}}</a> 
</td>
            {%endfor%}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{#<a href="{% url 'post_single' pk=post.fk_article %}">{{post.fk_article}} 
</a>#}

</div>
</div>
        </div>{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.views.generic import View
from django.db.models import Q
from .forms import SearchForm
from .models import Article, ArticleResearch


class CannabisView(View):

def get(self, request):
    form = SearchForm()
    #forms_type = TypeResearchForm()
    return render(request, 'cannabis/cannabis.html', {"form": form})

def post(self, request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    #forms_type = TypeResearchForm(request.POST)
    #if forms_type.is_valid():

    #if form.is_valid():
    number_of_patients = request.POST.get("number_of_patients") #form.cleaned_data["number"]
    type_research = request.POST.getlist("type_research", None) #form.cleaned_data["type_research"]
    disease = request.POST.get("disease") #form.cleaned_data["disease"]
    #print(type_research)
    filt = []

    if number_of_patients:
        num = Q()
        num &= Q(fk_article_research__number_of_pations__gte=number_of_patients)
        filt.append(num)
    if type_research:
        type_r = Q()
        type_r &= Q(fk_article_research__fk_type_of_research__id__in=type_research)
        filt.append(type_r)
    posts = Article.objects.filter(Q(fk_article_research__fk_disease__name__istartswith=disease)).filter(*filt)
    print(posts)
    return render(request, 'cannabis/cannabis.html', {"form": form, "posts": posts})
    #else:
        #return HttpResponse("Error")

 class PostViews(View):
 """Вывод статьи"""
 def get(self, request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Article, id=pk)
    return render(request, 'cannabis/post-single.html', {"post": post})



def search_form(request):
return render_to_response(request, 'cannabis/search-form.html')
```

Comment: Добавьте в пост вашу вьюху, пожалуйста.

Comment: добавила вьюху)

Answer (score 0):

Вы генерируете `posts` на сервер и потом создаете в Jinja страницу. Почему бы вам не отсортировать posts на сервере и не сгенерировать страницу с уже отсортированными данными? В случае если данные - это запрос к базе - просто использовать ORDER BY.

Как вариант, если у вас Jinja 2.6+, то можно попробовать вот так:

```
{% for art in post.fk_article_research.all|sort(attribute='fk_drug') %}
```

Comment: Это не Jinja, обычный `Django template language`.

Answer (score 0):

**1 вариант: сортировка через Мета-класс.**

К модели, на которую ссылается ключ `fk_article_research` добавить:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['fk_disease']
```

Судя по всему `fk_disease` тоже внешний ключ, следовательно к модели, на которую он ссылается также добавляем сортировку:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']  # тут название поля(полей), по которому нужно сортировать
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering

**2 вариант: сортировка property-методом модели.**

К модели `Article` добавляем новый метод и присваиваем ему декоратор `@property`:

```
@property
def fk_article_research_sorted(self):
    return self.fk_article.research.all().order_by('fk_disease__name')
```

Заменяем `post.fk_article_research.all` в шаблоне на `post.fk_article_research_sorted`.

О том, что такое `@property` можно почитать тут: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property
Если кратко - использование метода, как атрибута класса(без использования скобок `()`).

**3 вариант: использование темплейт-фильтра `dictsort`**

Заменяем `post.fk_article_research.all` в шаблоне на `post.fk_article_research.all|dictsort:"fk_disease.name"`

Почитать об этом можно тут: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort